# как в консоли firefox записать строки в файл

Tags: javascript

```
while (i < txt.length) {

    document.querySelector("#id").value = txt[i];

    if (document.querySelector("#id").value != ""){
        document.querySelector("#but").click();
        console.log( document.querySelector("#txt").innerText ); //хочу что бы вот этот вот текст вместо вывода сохранялся на диск в файл /home/user/log.txt

    } else{
        console.log("fields are not filled correctly");
    }

    i++;
}
```

вопрос в коментарии, как это сделать?

Comment: Вот статейка на тему работы с файлами на клиенте... https://habr.com/ru/companies/timeweb/articles/653703/

Comment: я, может, отстал от жизни, но js не имеет доступа к файловой системе. Только, если заставить браузер скачать файл.